# dataTables : javascript not working while paging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using dataTable for creating a table and everything is working fine. Table consists of a checkbox (column1) and select (last column). So my javascript will only enable select when checkbox is selected. While page to next page, javascript of enabling/disabling is not working. All the selects are enabled.

#### javascript

```
<script>
var update_selectopt=function(){
$("tr").each(function(){
    if($("input[type='checkbox']", this).is(":checked")){
        $('#select',this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
      $('#select',this).attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
    });
  };


$(update_selectopt);
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",update_selectopt);

</script>
```

How to manage that?

Comment: So it works fine on the initial page load, then after paging, it does not. Right?

Comment: yup..initial loading works fine...all the selects are disabled and enabled only after checking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire your `update_selectopt` function after the paging event has happened on the table:

```
$('#table_ws').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    update_selectopt();
});
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
$('#table_ws').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    update_selectopt();
});
```

Documentation on page event [here](http://datatables.net/reference/event/page)

Comment: So, if I go from page 1 to page 2, page 2 have all select enabled and when I flip from 1 to 2 again, then page 2 have select disabled, which is weird. So in short, first fire to that page is not working..and subsequent fire works.

Comment: Sounds like it's not initializing the page event until after the first time you page. Where did you add the event code I posted above?

Comment: $('#table_ws').on( 'page.dt', function () {
    update_selectopt();
});

$(update_selectopt);
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",update_selectopt);   This is how it is lined up

Comment: Okay, try changing the event from page to draw. I will update my answer with this new code.